# How to run a Java download command using shell in ansible

Tags: java, linux, ansible

I want to download and install Java in one our VMs using Ansible. I tried with `yum` and that was successful but, as part of requirement I was asked to do it another way.

To do so, I tried

```yaml
- name: "[version-update] Download Java "
  shell: 
    args:
      chdir: /opt/xcal/apps
```

Where the command to execute is

```sh
wget --no-check-certificate -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.rpm
```

But, while trying this the editor is showing errors.
I tried this command with a double quotes surrounding it and just pasting it but both are throwing errors.

I understand

```
"Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"
```

This is the part that's causing the issue. Is there a way to include this in the command as well?

Comment: Rather than trying to fix your command (which will basically [come down to fix a quoting issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/d5a83caba4efcb41c15eb7a8d0ac0b49)): using wget in shell is a bad practice. See the [`get_url`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html) or [`uri`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) modules

Comment: Thank you. Yes, instead of trying to fix the quoting issue I used get_url.

Comment: Note that fixing the quotes is perfectly feasible (as demonstrated in my above link for any future similar need) but using shell is still a bad practice here. Good move if you have it working with `get_url`.

Answer (score 0):

One working approach with the `shell` module can be

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Download Java
    shell:
      cmd: 'curl -x "localhost:3128" -O https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.rpm'
      chdir: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}"
      warn: false
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result }}"
```

An other one with the `get_url` module.

```yaml
  - name: Download Java
    get_url:
      url: "https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.rpm"
      dest: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}"
      use_proxy: true
    register: result
    environment:
      HTTP_PROXY: "localhost:3128"
      HTTPS_PROXY: "localhost:3128"

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result }}"
```

Comment: Why `curl` instead of original `wget`? Why do you set a proxy? Where is the initial cookie header which was the core of the question?

Comment: @Zeitounator, I understand the question as just "_How to run a Java download command using shell in Ansible? I want to download and install Java in one our VMs using Ansible. ..._". I haven't interpreted what was tried as a hard requirement and as a random approach. Regarding "_Where is the initial cookie header_", in my tests and environment there is no cookie necessary. The cookie might became introduced as in the past it was a requirement for downloads from Oracle and which is not the case anymore. So it is obsolete. The proxy is just to address my test environment and could be deleted.